# How to convert multiple images to .npy in python?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, project

I'm writing a code to detect facemask in jupyter notebook. I have 2000 images with masks and 2000 images without mask I need to convert that images into .npy folder which will contain all those images. how can I do that?
`
capture = cv2.imread('./dataset\with_mask/')
data = []
while True:
#flag, img = capture.read()
if flag:
faces= haar_data.detectMultiScale(img)
for x,y,w,h in faces:
face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w, :]
face = cv2.resize(face, (50,50))
cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w, y+h), (255,0,255), 4)

```
        print(len(data))
        if len(data) < 500:
            data.append(face)
    cv2.imshow('display',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(2)  == 27 or len(data) >=500: 
        break
```

#capture.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
`

Comment: Why is this tagged C++?

Comment: What have you tried?  Show us your code.  There are lots of examples of how to save .npy files.